# PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_Testcase returns undefined method

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, phpunit, tdd

Im getting a Fatal error: Call to undefined method PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DB_DefaultDatabaseConnection::prepare() on a phpunit test where I'm preparing a PDO statement. If the default database connection is a copy of the pdo object that successfully connects, wouldn't it have access to its methods?

My Class and the function in question:

```
class User
{ 
protected $db; 

public function __construct($db) 
{ 
$this->db = $db; 
} 

public function deleteItem($itemId)
{
$sql = "
DELETE FROM Users WHERE id = ?";
$sth = $this->db->prepare($sql);//this is the failed line works on other tests
return $sth->execute(array($itemId));
}
```

My Test:

```
class RosterDBTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_Testcase 
{ 

public function getConnection() 
{
 $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=users','root','root');
return $this->createDefaultDBConnection($pdo,"users"); 
} 

public function getDataSet()  
{  
return $this->createFlatXMLDataset(  
dirname(__FILE__) . '/users.xml');  
}  

public function setup()
{
$this->db = $this->getConnection();
}

public function testRemoveUser()
{
$testUser = new User($this->db);
$expectedUsers = 123;
$testUser->deleteItem(91);
$totalUsers = $testUsers->getAllUsers();
$this->assertEquals( $expectedUsers,count($totalUsers), 'Did not delete User 91' );
}
```

Comment: Same problem here...

Comment: Panique, in your connection try, the socket instead of localhost. ie: 'mysql:unix_socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock'

Answer (score 1):

I've just been stuck on  a similar problem where I had my abstract database testcase class. Solved it by changing

```
public function setup()
{
  $this->db = $this->getConnection();
}
```

to

```
public function setup()
{
  $this->db = $this->getConnection()->getConnection();
}
```

Not sure if this helps with this but hopefully will help someone.